# Communicating between a Windows Service and Exchange Server

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, exchange-server

I recently created a windows service which can wear various hats depending on what it needs to do. One of these hats is the ability to create update and delete outlook contacts on an exchange server. Before the windows service, the application ran as a windows app and used the outlook interop to get the job done. As a windows service that doesn't seem possible.

Now I'm looking at trying to go straight to Exchange to get the job done. Any hints or tips as far as what's the best way to communicate directly with Exchange, or any issues that may arise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to go to the [Exchange Server Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/default.aspx) to get more info on this.

Given your requirements, and since you're using C#, the [Exchange Web Services Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) is probably your best option.

Comment: While exchange was installing I took some more stabs at getting our old outlook interop code working. After some fooling around it appears to function without the need of writing new code to talk directly to Exchange. Essentially we needed to make the service run as a user that has an outlook profile set up. System Local apparently didn't. :P

do you think there Would be any significant benefits to talk straight to exchange at this point?

Comment: Communicating directly with exchange has 2 advantages: You don't need a user account, and you'll get much better performance, since you're removing the interop layer.  You also can do more things that aren't allowable via Outlook's API, since you have the full exchange API available.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Can you please help how did you implement it? I am looking for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091121/ms-exchange-logging-incoming-information-in-db